# list of all dll files associated with a program

Tags: windows-7

I am making a utility application in which I need to show  the information about the running programs.

Please tell me how to access **dll files** linked to the selected program file.

Answer (score 0):

There are some existing utilities that already give you this information:

- Dependency Walker can tell you which DLL's are needed by an executable
- Process Explorer gives can give you all the DLL's currently being used by a process

If you want to do this in your own utility, you should use the following Windows functions:

- Use OpenProcess to get the process handle of a running process with a known process id
- use EnumProcessModules to loop over all modules (EXE+DLL's) of the process
- in the loop function, use GetModuleBaseNameA or GetModuleFileNameEx to get the module name (file name)